# bash find lines starting with string

Tags: bash, sed, grep, string

I have a bunch of files and I want to find which one contains sequential lines starting with a certain string.

For example for the following file :

```
Aaaaaaaaaaaa
Baaaaaaaaaaa
Cxxxxxxxxx
Cyyyyyyyyy
Czzzzzzzzz
Abbbbbbbbbbb
Bbbbbbbbbbbb
Caaaaaa
Accccccccccc
Bccccccccccc
Cdddddd
Ceeeeee
```

There is more than one line starting with 'C', so I want this file to be found by command.
For example for the following file :

```
Aaaaaaaaaaaa
Baaaaaaaaaaa
Cxxxxxxxxx
Abbbbbbbbbbb
Bbbbbbbbbbbb
Caaaaaa
Accccccccccc
Bccccccccccc
Cdddddd
```

There is always one line starting with 'C', I don't want this file.
I thought of using a `grep` or a `sed` but I don't know exactly how to do it.
Maybe using a regexp `^C.*$^C` or something like that.
Any idea ?

Comment: There're two lines starting with `C` in your second example.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you looking for files that have more than one *consecutive* line starting with `C`?

Comment: Yes this is what I want. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I don't know who add an answer and then delete it but it was a good answer to what I am looking for : 

    `grep -rPl '^C.*\nC'`

Comment: Well, I assure you that it works for me. In the end I want to know which files have more than 2 consecutive lines starting with `C`, the command `grep -rPl '^C.*\nC.*\nC' filenames_pattern` works...

Comment: @terdon, it looks like multi-line searches with -P worked until 2.5.4 and not anymore after that, though I can't find anything in the changelog that would explain why.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas really? With no modifiers? Not even pure `perl` would match that! Thanks. Jérémie, I stand corrected, if your `grep` is old enough apparently it might work. Still wouldn't recommend it though since it won't work on newer machines (my `grep` version is from 2013 and that's already v. 2.15).

Comment: @Graeme you might want to undelete your answer, see Stephane's comment, apparently it does work for some older `grep` versions.

Comment: @terdon, actually, I suspect the change was unintentional and the documentation implies that multi-line should be supported. See http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.grep.bugs/5187 which I raised not so long ago (and now understand a bit more).

Comment: The change seems to have been introduced by [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=a14685c2833f7c28a427fecfaf146e0a861d94ba) so looks like it was intentional, but to fix some other bug, without taking into consideration that it was breaking a documented behaviour

Comment: Wow ! You're looking deep inside the thing ! My grep version is `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1` I use it through Cygwin in fact. What matters is that I needed this thing ponctually and it worked, so it is ok for me :) But I understand that you want to know why... !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -rMl '^C.*\nC' .
```

POSIXly:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '
  FNR==1 {last=0; printed=0; next}
  printed {next}
  /^C/ {if (last) {print FILENAME; printed=1; nextfile} else last=1; next}
  {last=0}' {} +
```

(though that means reading all the files fully with those `awk` implementations that don't support `nextfile`).

---

With versions of GNU `grep` up to 2.5.4:

```
grep -rlP '^C.*\nC' .
```

*appears* to work, but it's by accident and it is not guaranteed to work.

Before it was fixed in 2.6 (by [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=a14685c2833f7c28a427fecfaf146e0a861d94ba)), GNU `grep` had overlooked that the pcre searching function it was using would match on the whole buffer currently processed by `grep`, causing all sorts of surprising behavior. For instance:

```
grep -P 'a\s*b'
```

would match on a file containing:

```
bla
bla
```

This would match:

```
printf '1\n2\n' | grep -P '1\n2'
```

But this:

```
(printf '1\n'; sleep 1; printf '2\n') | grep -P '1\n2'
```

Or:

```
(yes | head -c 32766; printf '1\n2\n') > file; grep -P '1\n2' file
```

would not (as the `1\n2\n` is across two buffers processed by `grep`).

That behaviour ended up being documented though:

> 15- How can I match across lines?
>
> Standard grep cannot do this, as it is fundamentally line-based.
>       Therefore, merely using the '[:space:]' character class does not
>       match newlines in the way you might expect.  However, if your grep
>       is compiled with Perl patterns enabled, the Perl 's' modifier
>       (which makes '.' match newlines) can be used:
>
> ```
>      printf 'foo\nbar\n' | grep -P '(?s)foo.*?bar'
> ```

After it was fixed in 2.6, the documentation was not amended (I once reported it [there](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.grep.bugs/5187)).

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `exit` and `-exec \;` instead of nextfile?

Comment: @terdon, that would mean running one `awk` per file. You'd want to do that only if your `awk` doesn't support `nextfile` and you've got a large proportion of files that are large and have matching lines towards the beginning of the file.

Comment: How about this [grep technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/753731) ( I guess with more recent versions of GNU grep) that facilitates multiline matches by make the whole file look like a single string by setting line terminator to NUL - would you be aware if there are any limitations to it?

Comment: @1_CR, That would load the whole file in memory if there's no NUL character in there and that assumes lines don't contain NUL characters. Also note that older versions of GNU grep (which the OP has) can't use `-z` with `-P`. There's no `\N` without `-P`, you'd need to write it `$'[\01-\011\013-\0377]'` which would only work in C locales (see http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.grep.bugs/5187)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, very useful detail, thanks

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{if (p ~ /^C/ && $1 ~ /^C/) print; p=$1}' afile.txt
```

This will print contents of the file if there are consecutive lines starting with a `C`. The expression `(p ~ /^C/ && $1 ~ /^C/)` will look into successive lines in the file and will evaluate to true if the first character in both match `C`. If that is the case, the line will be printed.

In order to find all the files that have such a pattern, you can run the above awk through a `find` command:

```
find /your/path -type f -exec awk '{if (p ~ /^C/ && $1 ~ /^C/) {print FILENAME; exit;} p=$1}' {} \;
```

In this command, the `find` + `exec` will go through each of the files and perform similar `awk` filtering on each file and print its name via `FILENAME` if the awk expression evaluated to true. In order to avoid printing `FILENAME` multiple times for a single file with multiple matches the `exit` statement is used (thanks @terdon).

Comment: My question was not clear enough, I want to know the name of the files with more than one consecutive line starting with `C`

Comment: @Jérémie I updated my answer.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation of how this works? Also, there's no need for `flag`, just `exit` instead. That way, you don't need to keep processing files after a match has been found.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option with GNU `sed`:

For a single file:

```
sed -n -- '/^C/{n;/^C/q 1}' "$file" || printf '%s\n' "$file"
```

(though it will also report the files it cannot read).

For `find`:

```
find . -type f ! -exec sed -n '/^C/{n;/^C/q 1}' {} \; -print
```

The problem with unreadable files being printed can be avoided by writing it:

```
find . -type f -size +2c -exec sed -n '$q1;/^C/{n;/^C/q}' {} \; -print
```

Comment: Can you please detail the `sed -n '$q1;/^C/{n;/^C/q}'` ?

Comment: Anyone to explain me ?

Comment: @Jérémie `$q1` -- forces sed to quit with an error if pattern is not found. It also will finish with error if something is wrong with file (it's unreadable or broken). So it will quit with 0 exit status only in case pattern is found and it will be passed to print. Part with `/^C/{n;/^C/q` is pretty simple. If it find string that starts with C it will read the next line and if it also starts with C it will quit with zero exit status.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files are small enough to be read into memory:

```
perl -000ne 'print "$ARGV\n" if /^C[^\n]*\nC/sm' *
```

**Explanation:**

- -`000` : set `\n\n` as the record separator, this turns on paragraph mode which will treat paragraphs (separated by consecutive newlines) as single lines.
- `-ne` : apply the script given as an argument to `-e` to each line of the input file(s).
- `$ARGV` : is the file currently being processed
- `/^C[^\n]*\nC/` : match `C` at the beginning of a line (see the description of the `sm` modifiers below for why this works here) followed by 0 or more non-newline characters, a newline and then another C. In other words, find consecutive lines starting with `C`.
  *`//sm` : these match modifiers are (as documented [here]):

  > - **m** :
  >     Treat string as multiple lines. That is, change "^" and "$" from matching the start or end of line only at the left and right ends of the string to matching them anywhere within the string.
  > - **s**: Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

You could also do something ugly like:

```
for f in *; do perl -pe 's/\n/%%/' "$f" | grep -q 'C[^%]*%%C' && echo "$f"; done
```

Here, the `perl` code replaces newlines with `%%` so, assuming you have no `%%` in your input file (big *if* of course), the `grep` will match consecutive lines starting with `C`.

Answer (score 1):

#### SOLUTION:

```
( set -- *files ; for f ; do (
set -- $(printf %c\  `cat <$f`)
while [ $# -ge 1 ] ;do [ -z "${1#"$2"}" ] && {
    echo "$f"; break ; } || shift
done ) ; done )
```

#### DEMO:

First, we'll create a test base:

```
abc="a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z" 
for l in $abc ; do { i=$((i+1)) h= c= ;
    [ $((i%3)) -eq 0 ] && c="$l" h="${abc%"$l"*}"
    line="$(printf '%s ' $h $c ${abc#"$h"})"
    printf "%s$(printf %s $line)\n" $line >|/tmp/file${i}
} ; done
```

The above creates 26 files in *`/tmp`* named *`file1-26`.* In each file there are 27 or 28 lines beginning with the letters *`a-z`* and followed by the rest of the alphabet. Every 3rd file contains two consecutive lines in which the first character is duplicated.

#### SAMPLE:

```
cat /tmp/file12
...
aabcdefghijkllmnopqrstuvwxyz
babcdefghijkllmnopqrstuvwxyz
cabcdefghijkllmnopqrstuvwxyz
...
kabcdefghijkllmnopqrstuvwxyz
labcdefghijkllmnopqrstuvwxyz
labcdefghijkllmnopqrstuvwxyz
mabcdefghijkllmnopqrstuvwxyz
...
```

And when I change:

```
set -- *files
```

to:

```
set -- /tmp/file[0-9]*
```

I get...

#### OUTPUT:

```
/tmp/file12
/tmp/file15
/tmp/file18
/tmp/file21
/tmp/file24
/tmp/file3
/tmp/file6
/tmp/file9
```

So, in brief, the solution works like this:

> *`set`s* subshell positionals to all of your files, and for each
>
> *`set`s* a nested subshell's positionals to the first letter of each line in each file as it loops.
>
> *`[ tests ]`* if *`$1`* negates *`$2`* indicating a match, and if so
>
> > *`echoes`* the filename then *`break`s* the current loop iteration
>
> else *`shift`s* to the next single character positional to try again

Answer (score 0):

This script uses `grep` and `cut` to obtain line numbers of matching lines, and checks for any two consecutive numbers. The file is assumed a valid filename passed as the first argument to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

checkfile () {
 echo checking $1
 grep -n -E "^C.*$" $1 | cut -d: -f1 | while read linenum
     do
        : $[ ++PRV ] 
        if [ $linenum == $PRV ]; then return 1; fi
        PRV=$linenum
     done
     return 0
}

PRV="-1"
checkfile $1
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   echo Consecutive matching lines found in file $1
fi
```