# Find all words beginning with Q

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

How do I search a text file and list all the words begining with Q?

The file I am searching is Python source code.

The closest I have found to a soulution is [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121355/bash-find-lines-starting-with-string) but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
grep -o '\bQ\w*'
```

The `\b` matches a word boundary, i.e. the beginning of a word. Then it has to start with `Q` followed by any number of other word characters.

Comment: Alternatively, use the `-w` flag to grep, that effectively adds `\b` to beginning and end of the pattern.

Comment: @TobySpeight "to beginning *and end* of pattern" doesn't seem to be quite what the OP wants, though.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling OP asked for words - so `\b` at end is quite appropriate (and implied with a pattern ending in `\w`)

Comment: Forgot to mention - I did actually test, using `grep -ow 'Q\w*'`.

Comment: `grep -o '\bQ\w*' filename.py` and `grep -ow 'Q\w*' filename.py` both do exactly what I wanted - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly:

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]_' '[\n*]' | grep '^Q'
```

A note that GNU `tr` won't work properly with multi-byte characters.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe this will help:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-search-find-file-for-text-string/

you can use "find" and then exec a command like "grep" and look for words starting with "Q*"

Example:

```
find . -type f -name *.py -exec grep --color Q* {} \;
```

! find . means in the current directory.
U can also use find / <= means find start from the root dir.

Comment: Did you try this? (1) The `*.py` will be expanded by the shell, which will cause `find` to complain if it expands to more than one file name. (2) `grep --color Q* {}` will execute grep on each matching file (not too bad) highlighting every place where `Q` occurs (not what the OP wants, because this will match the word `pkQuest` just as much as the word `Quest`). Please take care to ensure that your answers match the requirements stated in the question, testing them if you are unsure.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: You’re such an optimist!  You didn’t look closely enough at the unquoted `Q*`.  If there are two or more files whose names begin with `Q` in the current directory (say, `Quack` and `Quake` (and maybe others)), then it will search for “`Quack`” in `Quake` (and the others) once for each file `find` finds.  If there’s one `Q` file (`Quack`), then the command will search for “`Quack`” in all the `*.py` files.  And (saving the best (?) for last), if there are no `Q` files, then this will report every line of every file (i.e., every that has a string of ***zero** or more* `Q`s).

Comment: Well i've tried with at least 10 *.py files in a directory.
The mistake id made was the "".
This command will search for files that end with .py and will give a output of the filename and with every word that starts with Q.
Maybe im wrong ..cos on my MacOSX this works perfectly. ;-)


`# find . -type f -name "*.py"  -exec grep -H --color "Q*" {} \;`

Comment: This might be a good answer to a different question. 1. This searches every .py file and I only need to search one specific one.   2.  On my Ubuntu machine it prints every line that contains a word starting with a Q.

Comment: Instead of using "*.py" u can specified a "filename" This way "find" will search only for the specified filename and print words that begins with Q

Comment: What version of `grep` do you use? At least GNU grep will use regex syntax instead of glob syntax, i.e. `Q*` will be "zero or more Q" and `Q.*` will be "Q followed by zero or more arbitrary characters".

Comment: Macbook air running OSX 10.10.4

#grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD